# Show that $S = \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : |x| + |y| < 1 \} $ is an open set.

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $S =  \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : |x| + |y| < 1 \} $ is an open set.

[image]

My intuition is that the radius for an epsilon ball around any given point in the set should be $ \epsilon = \{1 - max(\{|x|\},\{|y|\}) \}$, but I am not sure. Hints appreciated.

Comment: I dont even get where the condition on the centers is imposed. *puzzled*

Comment: Right, I am having difficulty expressing what I mean. I want the ball to be contained within the square.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Contained within the square but around every of the squares border-points is a contradiction - I am sure I am not understanding you correctly, please help me get your point.

Comment: Right there should have been an inequality.

Comment: Such a "ball" with respect to the standard norm would still be impossible.

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: Or wait - maybe you mean a separate ball for each point satisfying the inequality?

Comment: @mol3574710n0fN074710n yes.

Comment: Ahhh, ok - then there are many, as you can make the balls for the "inner" points small. Do you want them as large as possible?

Comment: doesn't matter really just trying to get a generic solution lol so I can understand the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will choose the radius depending on the distance to the lines.
Let $d((x,y), L) = \frac{|ax+by+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$be the distance from a point to a straight line.
Then the radius $r = \min(d((x,y), L_1), d((x,y), L_2), d((x,y), L_3), d((x,y), L_4)) $
Where $ L_1: y = x+1; L_2: y= -x+1; L_3 : y= x-1; L_4 : y= -x-1 $

Comment: Sorry, if I misunderstood you, it seemed to me that you are proving that this figure is open in the standard metric of Euclidean space.

Comment: I like this a lot, this was what I was thinking in the first place.

Comment: Ask, if something is not clear in my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, we want an open ball that lies in the drawn region. If it's a ball, then it has a constant radius $r$, and the largest $r$ can be so that it doesn't go out of bounds is where $|x| + |y| = 1$ is closest to the origin, which is the bisector between $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$

let d be the distance between $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$

$d =\sqrt{1^2+1^2} = \sqrt{2}$

$r = \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{d}{2}\right)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Thus any open ball with radius $0<\rho \leq r$ satisfies $|x|+|y|\leq1$

Comment: I think the question is *really* asking to prove that $S = \{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert < 1\}$ is an open set, i.e. by finding an open ball around each point $(x, y)\in S$ that lies entirely in $S$.

Comment: Ah I see now, my apologies for misinterpreting the question

Answer (score 0):

For $x$ and $y$ such that $\left|x\right|+\left|y\right|<1$
  we want to find an open ball $B_{d\left(x,y\right)}\left(x,y\right)$
  with radius $d\left(x,y\right)$
  such that for all $\left(a,b\right)\in B_{d\left(x,y\right)}\left(x,y\right)$
  holds $\left|a\right|+\left|b\right|<1$
 .

We will try to make this ball "large".

We require for the radius $d\left(x,y\right)$
  of the ball around $\left(x,y\right)$, that for arbitrary angles $\varphi$:

\begin{array}{cc}
 & \left|x+d\left(x,y\right)\cdot\cos\varphi\right|+\left|y+d\left(x,y\right)\cdot\sin\varphi\right|\\
\leq & \left|x\right|+\left|y\right|+\left|d\left(x,y\right)\right|\cdot\left(\left|\cos\varphi\right|+\left|\sin\varphi\right|\right)\\
\leq & \left|x\right|+\left|y\right|+\left|d\left(x,y\right)\right|\cdot\sqrt{2}\\
\overset{!}{<} & 1
\end{array}

Thus:

$$d\left(x,y\right)=\frac{1-\left|x\right|-\left|y\right|}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: This is one consequence of my answer, in fact